# Figure margins too large

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm working with the olive data set in base R (see below for data accession instructions). I want to plot palmitic fats against palmitoleic fats, but when I type:

```
library(dslabs)
data(olive)
plot(olive$palmitic, olive$palmitoleic)
```

The response is, `Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large`

It's a pretty basic command. What's going wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: If this is RStudio, just use the mouse to adjust the size of the plot window? I seem to recall having that error once and fixing it in such an easy way.

Comment: Your code does not give me that error..

Comment: @JohnColeman that was it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to use my mouse to adjust the size of the plot window